# Logback Modify log level in Custom Logging Filter

Tags: java, logging, logback

My goal is to capture errors thrown by org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper and log them as warn

**CustomLoggingFilter.java**

```
package com.example.service;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomLoggingFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

  private final String exceptionClassName = "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper";

  public CustomLoggingFilter() {
  }

  @Override
  public FilterReply decide(final ILoggingEvent event) {
    if (event.getLoggerName().equals(exceptionClassName)) {
      return FilterReply.DENY;
    }

    return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
  }
}
```

My xml config

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

  <appender name="SqlAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="com.example.service.CustomLoggingFilter" />

    <encoder>
      <pattern>
        %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="SqlAppender"/>
  </logger>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

I could prevent the message from being logged but not sure how to **log it as warn instead of error**.

P.S: Not sure if my approach is correct

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have it configured as ERROR currently?

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="SqlAppender"/>
  </logger>
```

try change this to:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="SqlAppender"/>
  </logger>
```

Comment: I think changing it to `level="WARN"` will capture logger.warn events (Correct me if I am wrong). I want it to capture ERROR level events and log them as WARN instead